# Открывается новое окно в браузере c# + selenium webdriwer

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2010

Приветствую. Есть проблемы при использовании selenium на c#. Нужно, чтобы программа запускала определённый сайт( не только на моём пк), и производила нажатия на кнопки. Суть проблемы в том, что запускает программа новое окно, а не то, которое использует человек - следственно, ему придётся входит на сайты, даже если на основном окне он залогинен.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;


namespace scammer_bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IWebDriver Browser;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
            Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://opskins.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Для работы с селениумом требуется, чтобы браузер был запущен через WebDriver. А там уже можно подключаться через SessionId